# Gnus stuck at "Reading .newsrc.eld..."

Tags: osx, gnus

I have just today started using gnus to read news groups.
I played around with subscribing and unsubscribing from certain groups, and read a few threads.

I exit gnus and emacs, and now when I try to reenter into Gnus, I am stuck on the loading screen (with the blue horse) with the minibuffer indicating

```
Reading /Users/samlaf/.newsrc.eld...
```

Is there a way to reconfigure this file, or might I have possibly changed some configurations that would cause such a problem?

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, reproduce the problem, and hit `C-g` when it's stuck. That should give you a backtrace that should help identifying the problem. (BTW, the blue "horse" is supposed to be a gnu :) )

Comment: I am stuck at the same place. Emacs is hung even "ESC ESC ESC", "C-g" and "M-x" not working. First time in my 20 years of editing in Emacs.